# Read dictionary from dat file

Tags: c#, file, dictionary, filestream, binaryreader

I wrote Dictionary to dat file , my Dictionary look like:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>>
```

Now my problem is to read from file the Dictionary ,I tried to use BinaryReader and StreamReader but my Dictionary is still null.

My write code:

```
static void WriteToFile(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dic)

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FILE_NAME, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
            StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs);
          BinaryFormatter bw = new BinaryFormatter();
        bw.Serialize(fs,dic);
            w.Write(dic);
```

My read code :

```
FileStream fs = newFileStream(FILE_NAME , FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
streamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string,string>> main = r.read();
```

Someone have any idea what can I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your need to perform read `r.read()`. Then - deserialize readed structure.

Note, that it is good practice to put `IDisposable` objects into `using` statement.

```
    static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> ReadFromFile()
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream("C:/test.dat", FileMode.Open))
        {
                var bw = new BinaryFormatter();
                return (Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>)bw.Deserialize(fs);
        }
    }

    static void WriteToFile(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> dic)
    {
        using (var fs= new FileStream("C:/test.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            using (var w = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                var bw = new BinaryFormatter();
                bw.Serialize(fs, dic);
                w.Write(dic);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `OpenOrCreate` for reading? Why would you want to create it? It will throw exception I guess if empty stream is passed to `Deserialize`.

Comment: Frankie how could I do this , how could I deserialize readed structurd?
 Sriram yes you right I fixed this .

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: yes, you are right. my error. Should be FileMode.Open. I didn't provide validations.